# shell script for listing all images in current and subfolder and copy them into one folder?

Tags: shell

I have some folder hierarchy, in some of the folders there are images, I need a shell script which can list all images and copy them into one specified folder, where listing them is not important, I just want to copy all images into a folder?

I know I can

```
ls -R *.png
```

but how do I copy them all to one folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** As glenn jackman has pointed out, this would be slightly more efficient to use over the answer I provided:

```
file . -type f -name \*.png | xargs cp -t destination
```

*For the explanation, see glenn's comments that follow this answer.*

---

One way is to use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec cp {} ~/path/to/your/destination/folder \;
```

**Explanation**:

- `find` is used to find files / directories
- `.` start finding from the current working directory (alternatively, you can specify a path)
- `-type f`: only consider files (as opposed to directories)
- `-name "*.png"`: only consider those with png extension
- `-exec`: for each such result found, do something (see below)
- `cp {} ~/path/to/your/destination/folder \;`: this is the do something part: copy each such result found (substituted into the `{}`) to the destination specified.

Comment: can gain slight efficiency with `file . -type f -name \*.png | xargs cp -t destination`

Comment: @glennjackman oh neat! would you mind explaining (or pointing me to some reading on) why xargs would be slightly more efficient here?

Comment: With `find ... -exec cp`, the cp command is spawned for every filename. With xargs, the cp command is built up with several filenames, so cp is spawned fewer times. The savings will be in the order of a (small) fraction of a second, and most likely will be completely overwhelmed by potential disk i/o.

Comment: @glennjackman this is actually quite helpful to learn; thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

To copy multiple file patterns in single go we can use **-regex** instead **-name**

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|gif\|mp4\|avi\|svg\|mp3\|vob\)' -exec cp {} /path/to/your/destination/folder \;
```